# Element type invalid error when passing in object into export function... in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a blog page where I'm trying to pass in generic data stored in an object inside an array for now. The error I'm getting is "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object" it's unclear to me where I'm going wrong. I've exported everything properly and imported my function in the component I'm using it in. I've googled the heck out of this issue and everything points to incorrectly exporting functions. Eventually, I'd like to modify this code to request the data from an external API. My question is how can I get this code to work with my dummy data in the array and then what is the ideal way to do this with an API?

Blog.js :

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

// import react slick
import Image from "next/image";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import ArrowBack from "../public/assets/Icon/eva_arrow-back-fill.svg";
import ArrowNext from "../public/assets/Icon/eva_arrow-next-fill.svg";
import Stars from "../public/assets/Icon/stars.svg";

const Blog = ({
  listBlog = [
    {
      name: "mj",
      image: "/assets/jordan.png",
      city: "Wilmington",
      country: "USA",
      rating: "5.0",
      blog: "Wow... MJ is the goat of the sport of basketball no one is remotely close",
    },
    {
      name: "Dj",
      image: "/assets/jeter.png",
      city: "Kalamazoo",
      country: "USA",
      rating: "4.5",
      blog: "5 Time world champion and clutch player of the last 25 years",
    },
    {
      name: "Tyson",
      image: "/assets/tyson.png",
      city: "Brooklyn",
      country: "USA",
      rating: "4.5",
      blog: "One of the most ferocious fighters of our lifetime and a true legend Tyson is the baddest man on the planet!",
    },
    {
      name: "Kobe",
      image: "/assets/kobe.png",
      city: "Philadelphia",
      country: "USA",
      rating: "4.5",
      blog: "The mamba mentality defined Kobe Bryant and his legacy will live on forever",
    },
  ],
}) => {
  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    customPaging: function (i) {
      return (
        <a className="">
          <span className="mx-2 rounded-l-full rounded-r-full h-4 w-4 block cursor-pointer transition-all "></span>
        </a>
      );
    },
    dotsClass: "slick-dots w-max absolute mt-20  ",
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 770,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
          initialSlide: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
  const [sliderRef, setSliderRef] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Slider
        {...settings}
        arrows={false}
        ref={setSliderRef}
        className="flex items-stretch justify-items-stretch"
      >
        {listBlog.map((listBlogs, index) => (
          <div className="px-3 flex items-stretch" key={index}>
            <div className="border-2 border-gray-500 hover:border-orange-500 transition-all rounded-lg p-8 flex flex-col">
              <div className="flex flex-col xl:flex-row w-full items-stretch xl:items-center">
                <div className="flex order-2 xl:order-1">
                  <Image
                    src={listBlogs.image}
                    height={50}
                    width={50}
                    alt="Icon People"
                  />
                  <div className="flex flex-col ml-5 text-left">
                    <p className="text-lg text-black-600 capitalize">
                      {listBlogs.name}
                    </p>
                    <p className="text-sm text-black-500 capitalize">
                      {listBlogs.city},{listBlogs.country}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-none items-center ml-auto order-1 xl:order-2">
                  <p className="text-sm">{listBlogs.rating}</p>
                  <span className="flex ml-4">
                    <Stars className="h-4 w-4" />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p className="mt-5 text-left">“{listBlogs.Blog}”.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Slider>
      <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-end">
        <div className="flex flex-none justify-between w-auto mt-14">
          <div
            className="mx-4 flex items-center justify-center h-14 w-14 rounded-full bg-white border-orange-500 border hover:bg-orange-500 hover:text-white-500 transition-all text-orange-500 cursor-pointer"
            onClick={sliderRef?.slickPrev}
          >
            <ArrowBack className="h-6 w-6 " />
          </div>
          <div
            className="flex items-center justify-center h-14 w-14 rounded-full bg-white border-orange-500 border hover:bg-orange-500 hover:text-white-500 transition-all text-orange-500 cursor-pointer"
            onClick={sliderRef?.slickNext}
          >
            <ArrowNext className="h-6 w-6" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to lie within this line `<p className="mt-5 text-left">“{listBlogs.Blog}”.</p>`. There's no property called `Blog` in your object. It should be `blog`. Do let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.